# Cantor Set : Characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, characteristic-functions, cantor-set

What is the characteristic function of the C Cantor set?

I already found that the function is Integrable but i couldn't find the exact result of the charateristic function of the C Cantor set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already know what the cantor set is. In that case, the characteristic function is the function $f$ with $f(x)=1$ for $x \in C$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You must employ a Lebesgue integration as $\chi_C$, the characteristic function of $C$,  is not classically or even Riemann integrable because its set of discontinuities,which is $ C$ , is uncountable.The measure  $\mu (I \backslash C)=\mu([0,1]\backslash C)= 1$ so $\mu (C)=0$ so $\chi_C (x)=0$ almost everywhere (which means except on a set of measure  0 ).If  Lebesgue-integrable functions $f ,g$ are equal  a.e. (almost everywhere) then $ \int_0^1 f(x) \mu( dx)=\int_0^1 g(x) \mu (dx)$.

Comment: $\mu (S)$  is the Lebesgue measure of the set $ S$ and  $[0,1]\backslash C=\{ x\in [0,1] : x \not \in C\}$  and  $[0,1]=\{x : 0\leq x \leq 1\}.$

Comment: The  first answer doesn't say what the integral is. It appears to be a hint.

Comment: I dk what you mean. For sets $ A,B$ with$ B\subset A$,the characteristic function of $ B$ is the function $ f:A\to \{0,1\} $ with $ f(x)=1$ when $x \in B$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x \in A\backslash B$. Usually,which set $A$ is the domain of $f$ is understood from further context.

Comment: The characteristic function IS Riemann integrable because its set of discontinuities has a Lebesgue measure $0$ and it is bounded.

Comment: A bounded function is Riemann integrable iff it has countably many discontinuities.$\chi _C$ is discontinuous at every point of $C$.

Comment: I don't know what definition of Riemann Integrability you have used, but if you use the Wikipedia definition, there are also Riemann integrable functions which have a uncountable number of discontinuities